# Single prediction after training Graph Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, predict, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I'm learning about Graph Neural Networks using [PyTorch Geometric lib](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io), but I don't know how to solve a trick question.

The docs have a very nice [list of Collab](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/colabs.html) code for each graph problem. For example, I'm using this one about [Link Prediction on the MovieLens dataset](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xpzn1Nvai1ygd_P5Yambc_oe4VBPK_ZT?usp=sharing).

I can complete all the `#TODO`s on this code and do the training part of the Neural Network. It's working fine, I receive an excellent accuracy score after iterating over my validation dataset. My problem is: What should I do now to predict a single missing link?

When I run `output = model(test_data)`, I receive a Tensor with some positive and negative values (see below) that do not mean much to me.

```
output = model(test_data)
print(output)

tensor([ -0.2850,   2.7798,   3.7315,  ..., -10.3339,  -6.0439,  -5.1031],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
```

Since I found some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051417/how-to-predict-a-single-sample-with-keras) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964307/how-to-interpret-predictions-from-a-neural-network) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864745/how-to-make-a-single-prediction-at-a-time-from-my-keras-neural-net) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051417/how-to-predict-a-single-sample-with-keras) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427432/linear-regression-with-multiple-features-how-to-make-a-prediction-after-traini) in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989130/make-prediction-after-finished-training), but none helped me, I will describe clearly what I want and avoid duplications.

I want to know how I can create a function that receives two nodes and give me the probability of having a link between a movie and a user.

```
def is_there_a_link(user, movie):
    //What code goes here?
    if prediction > 0.5:
        # more than 50%
        return 'YES'
    else:
        return 'NO'

#Should I recommend the movie with id 3 for the user with id 1?
prediction = is_there_a_link(test_data['user'].node_id[1], test_data['movie'].node_id[3])
```

I also looked at this [video](https://youtu.be/m1G7oS9hmwE) on PyG documentation with a slightly different implementation. Still, it also ends after validation (Other PyTorch tutorials on the web always stop after validation too). What I should do next is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run `output = model(test_data)`, I receive a Tensor with some positive and negative values (see below) that do not mean much to me.

That's because it's not probabilities, it's probability [logits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit)

To get the probabilities you need to run

```python
output = model(test_data)
probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=0)
print(probabilities)
```